# How can we retrive style from css by selector without creating element?

Tags: javascript, css

Suppose we have 2 css files
First has

```
.x { background-color="red" }
```

second has

```
div { border=1 }
div:hover { border=2 }
```

How can we get style of  by javascript without creating new element just to get its style?

And even if we need to create new element for get the style or not. How we can get it with and without hover ?

Are there any functionality like document.queryStyle({ type:"div",class:"x",hover:true }) or anything like this?

Comment: You can by using chrome dev tools, but programmatically I am not sure that you can force hover styles to kick in. You could always write a simple CSS parser.

Comment: You'll have to create an element to get the computed style. Also, you'll need to make use of a class selector for hover.

Comment: Create a new element with Javascript, get its style and remove it afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is usually no problem with creating the element and removing the element right after, because the visitor will never see it.

Solution with jquery:

```
$div = $('<div class="border"></div>');
$('body').append($div);
var css = $div.css("border");
$div.remove();
```

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    hello world
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.border {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ypUKC/

If you really can't create the element, google for "Javascript CSS Parser".

By the way, your CSS Syntax is incorrect. It's "div { border: 1px; }", not "div { border = 1 }"

Comment: Thank you very much. I just don't want to create overhead as much as possible but if it need to I would do that. But the problem is I don't know how to get css with hover(and other event) style with this method. Do you know how? Can I force triggering mouseover event before retrieve css?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you all's help. I have [found a method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle) I need for retrive style with event selector